# How to use multiple parameters in PowerShell script separated by commas?

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-3.0

I am trying to `mstsc` to multiple servers, but I am stuck on how to proceed. I don't want to use credentials, just open up the window.

I have

```
param([parameter(Mandatory=$True)] $Servername
mstsc /v: $Servername
```

So I can just call out `PS> script servername`

But I am trying to figure out how to just input multiple servers in the PS window such as:

`PS> script1 server1, server2, server3`, ... and whatever I need

And all of them should be passed through `mstsc /v: server1 - server3`

Is this possible in PowerShell and if so, how?

Comment: If you dont want to enter password everytime, I would use the .rdp file and save the credentials there, you can automate rdp file creation and then just execute those from script.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a function to do this. Instead use either a `foreach` loop or the `foreach-object` construct.

```
'Server1','server2' | 
    foreach-object {mstsc.exe /v: $_ }
```

or

```
Get-content path_to_servers.txt | 
    foreach-object {mstsc.exe /v: $_ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `ServerName` parameter as type `[string[]]` in the param block and then launch `mstsc` for each string:

#### script1.ps1

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
  [string[]]$ServerName
)

foreach($Name in $ServerName){
    mstsc.exe /v $Name
}
```

now you can do:

```
PS> .\script1.ps1 server1,server2,server3
```

---

PS. I would be inclined to use the parameter name `ComputerName` rather than `ServerName`

Comment: @willcha65 you're welcome. If this solves your problem, click the checkmark on the left to mark the answer as "accepted"